# How to move gameObject only 1 Unity unit using the keyboard?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to make a puzzle-platformer game. The main character can move up, right, down or left using the arrow keys. Everything is working well if I press the arrows every move. But, I want the character to keep moving if the arrow is pressed down and stop when I lift my fingers.

Here is my code:

```
void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            direction = 2;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            direction = 3;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            direction = 4;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            direction = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.DownArrow) ||
            Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow) ||
            Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow) ||
            Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            direction = 0;
        }
        movePacman();
    }

private void movePacman()
    {  
        switch (direction)
        {
            case 1:
                moveRight();              
                break;
            case 2:
                moveDown();              
                break;
            case 3:
                moveLeft();               
                break;
            case 4:
                moveUp();              
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Using the code my Pacman sometimes makes 2 moves if I don't lift my finger fast enough.

How this can be solved?

Comment: This is because the input is read every frame, try to decrement it, like take the input after a certain time, i.e. read input after every 0.5s or something

Comment: @GeekyQuentin I can use a counter in the update method, but then the game will be sluggish. I want good and smooth control over the pacman.

Comment: What exactly do you want then? Do you want a slight delay when the finger is pressed for the first time?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin No, when I lift my finger from the arrows key - Pacman needs to stop moving. If I press down on a arrow key - only 1 Unity unit movement should occur.

Comment: Then you are probably looking for `GetKeyDown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your movement functions( up , down , left, right )are the main key are you adding velocity or are you changing the transform.posistion ?
- Your switch case does not have "case 0: ". you can create a stop movement function and mention in case 0
- Instead of keeping movePacman(); in update function, call it only when any keys are down.
- You can also directly call respective movement functions in if functions of key down. ( if "Up Arrow" is clicked --> moveUp(); )
- Also think of using Nested if function.

Comment: I'm changing the transform position, I don't have a rigid body as I don't need one. How to read the keyboard input if not inside of the update function?

Comment: As per my knowledge there are no callback functions for keyboard input, you will have to check it every frame or at least when you are expecting an input.

Other alternative is to use UNITY INPUT SYSTEM. You can explore the basics by watching this video by Unity : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tOOstXaIKE&t=2s